# Do I need to combine the Filter function with an Array in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, flatten

I have the following formula in Google Sheets.

**=filter('2. Student Scores'!$C$1:$CD$1,(filter('2. Student Scores'!$C:$CD,row('2. Student Scores'!$A:$CD)=match(A2,'2. Student Scores'!A:A,0))=0))**

I need the formula to continue down the list of column A values so it automatically carries out this function for A3, A4, A5 and so on.

How do I make this happen automatically? Using it in combination with an array function doesn't seem to work. Changing the Match range doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Share a copy of sample workbook. You can't use `FILTER()` function as array function. Show your dummy data and desired output.

Comment: Here's the link - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ee6l79hNgzvlf8j4hzJwiJpqDYzKoZ3uWFPsZI0bj-o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The "Question Number Filter" tab is the one I'm trying to edit. Rather than dragging the formula down, I'd like Column B to populate automatically.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFNA(
 VLOOKUP(A2:A, {'2. Student Scores'!A5:A, 
 IF('2. Student Scores'!C5:CD=0, '2. Student Scores'!C1:CD1, )}, 
 COLUMN('2. Student Scores'!B1:CC1), 0))),,9^9))), " ")))
```

[image]

Comment: You're a legend. Thank you so much. Can I ask, where did you learn about Google Sheets queries and indexes, etc.? I know the basics in Excel/Sheets but would like to expand my knowledge.

Comment: @Kamilah for me it was the old good trial and error. I used to find some question on SO, open up the spreadsheet and play with it until solved. back then it would take me hours or even days, now its 5 minutes.